# How to convert this array to json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a form where users can choose multiple items using checkboxes when each item have data like below. I have tried to get json data from input value.

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
 <input name="orders[]" type="checkbox" value='"name":"{{ $order->user_name }}","address":"{{ $order->user_address }}"' >
@endforeach
```

I need to store each checked item with several data. In the model i am getting data like this.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => ""name":"Uzzwal Dhali","address":"""
  1 => ""name":"Priyanka","address":"Sarobaor""
  2 => ""name":"Uzzwal Dhali","address":"""
]
```

How to convert to JSON?

Comment: Why don't you just have a separate input for each of these? The only way to do this would be to make the value itself a JSON string, which is not recommended when there are much better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Your question is still unclear.

Comment: You can not store value-attribute as an array. It must be a string.

Comment: Please have a check, I have edited my post to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in laravel but I guess you would figure it out by code written below. I hope this is what you meant:

```
<?php
//Example orders
$orders = [
    ["name"=>"item name1",
    "colour"=>"item colour1",
    "price"=>"price1"],
    ["name"=>"item name2",
    "colour"=>"item colour2",
    "price"=>"price2"],
    ["name"=>"item name3",
    "colour"=>"item colour3",
    "price"=>"price3"]
];
$encoded_json = json_encode($_POST,true);

//Actual form
echo '<form method="post">';
foreach($orders as $order_item) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $order_item['name'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]" value="<?php echo $order_item['colour'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $order_item['price'];?>">
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>

//Encoded JSON after posted form would look like: (If you just check some checkboxes)
{
    "colour":["item colour1","item colour2"],
    "price":["price1","price2"],
    "name":["item name3"]
}
```

**UPDATE**
Organising the response from the form differently by changing foreach-loop above:

```
foreach($orders as $key=>$order_item) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][name]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['name'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][colour]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['colour'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][price]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['price'];?>">
<?php
}
```

**Output** (if all checkboxes are checked)

```
{
"orders":[
    {"name":"item name1","colour":"item colour1","price":"price1"},
    {"name":"item name2","colour":"item colour2","price":"price2"},
    {"name":"item name3","colour":"item colour3","price":"price3"}
]}
```

**Output** (if name and price in the first item is checked)

```
{
"orders":[
    {"name":"item name1","price":"price1"}
]}
```

**UPDATE2:**

Above will only include values in the encoded that are actually sent (if the user does not check the checkboxes they will not be sent as post).

This is a way of making sure all values are encoded as json even if the checkbox(es) are not checked:

```
<?php
$orders = [
    ["name"=>"item name1",
    "colour"=>"item colour1",
    "price"=>"price1"],
    ["name"=>"item name2",
    "colour"=>"item colour2",
    "price"=>"price2"],
    ["name"=>"item name3",
    "colour"=>"item colour3",
    "price"=>"price3"]
];

//Create template orders which is basically a copy of $orders
//but with empty strings
$template_orders = [];
foreach($orders as $outer_key=>$inner_arr) {
    foreach($inner_arr as $key=>$item) {
        $template_orders['orders'][$outer_key][$key] = '';
    }
}
//Fill in values for those keys that actually exists from posted valeus
foreach($template_orders['orders'] as $key=>$item) {
    foreach(array_keys($item) as $ikey) {
        if (isset($_POST['orders'][$key][$ikey])) {
            $template_orders['orders'][$key][$ikey] = $_POST['orders'][$key][$ikey];
        }
    }
}

$encoded_json = json_encode($template_orders);

echo '<form method="post">';
foreach($orders as $key=>$order_item) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][name]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['name'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][colour]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['colour'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="orders[<?php echo $key;?>][price]" 
    value="<?php echo $order_item['price'];?>">
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

***This could output ($encoded_json) :*** (name of first and second item is not checked, price is not checked in second item and colour is not checked in third item)

```
"orders":[
    {"name":"","colour":"item colour1","price":"price1"},
    {"name":"","colour":"item colour2","price":""},
    {"name":"item name3","colour":"","price":"price3"}
]}
```

Comment: Each item have data likes "name"=>"item name1",
    "colour"=>"item colour1",
    "price"=>"price1" . When someone will check a checkbox then a set of data will input. If two checkboxes are checked then two set of data....